# Slider and ngModel lagging with finger slide

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm running into a performance issue with the Slider component.

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label text="time {{time}} minutes"></Label>
  <Slider minValue=1  maxValue=120 [(ngModel)]="time"></Slider>
</StackLayout>
```

When I run this on my emulator and device (Nexus 5x) the slider number lags when I use it.  I have to go slower than I normally would to get the number to update with the position of my finger.

Is there a better way to implement this kind of slider where the number matches the position of my finger at any speed I slide across it, with no lag?

This gif is from the above code and shows the lag. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzyy9.gif

Comment: Could be https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311 which should be included in the next Angular update. You can try to set `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some research and found that one possible solution to handle this lag is to update manually the text property of the Label. You could define `onchange` method for the Slider and to handle the change of its value.

In regard to that you could review my sample code below:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"; 
import {CustomComponent} from "./custom.component"

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    directives:[CustomComponent],
    template: `
<StackLayout style="background-color: green;" >

    <Label [text]="time + 'minutes'"></Label>
        <Slider #sl minValue=1  maxValue=120 [value]="time" (valueChange)="onchange(sl.value)"></Slider>
    </StackLayout>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    public time:number=30;

    public onchange(newtime){
        this.time=newtime;
    }
}
```